# Openlayers - get properties from automatic searching selection

Tags: openlayers, wfs, search, fields-attributes

I want to get the feature property from a selection. The Selection is comming from a search reference, from the openlayers extension (by http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/).
It works almost everything, except the property. I get a "a is undefined" Error and can not explain it to me.
The last section refers to the properties.

```
var defaultStyle_polygon_1 = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(251, 209, 88, 0.4)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(251, 209, 88, 1)',
        width: 2
    }),
});
var openstreetmap = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});
var polygon_source = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
        return 'https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/geometry/senstadt/re_schutzgebiete?service=WFS&' + 'version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=re_schutzgebiete&' + 'outputFormat=application/json&crs=EPSG:25833&' + 'Filter=%3CFilter%3E%3CPropertyIsEqualTo%3E%3CPropertyName%3ESCHUTZSTATUS%3C/PropertyName%3E%3CLiteral%3EFFH-Gebiet%3C/Literal%3E%3C/PropertyIsEqualTo%3E%3C/Filter%3E';
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
        minZoom: 10
    }))
});
var polygons = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: polygon_source,
    style: defaultStyle_polygon_1
});
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        openstreetmap,
        polygons
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([13.3833, 52.5167], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:25833'),
        zoom: 9,
    }),
});
var select = new ol.interaction.Select({});
map.addInteraction(select);
var search = new ol.control.SearchFeature({
    source: polygon_source,
    property: "GEBIETSNAME"
});
map.addControl(search);
var selectedFeatures = [];
selectFeaturesGlobal = selectedFeatures;
search.on('select', function(e) {
    select.getFeatures().clear();
    select.getFeatures().push(e.search);
    var p = e.search.getGeometry().getFirstCoordinate();
    map.getView().animate({
        center: p,
        zoom: 13
    });
});
search.on('select', function(event) {
    var selectedFeatures = [];
    selectFeaturesGlobal = selectedFeatures;
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        console.log(feature.get('GEBIETSNAME'));
        selectedFeatures.push(feature);
    });
    if (selectedFeatures.length > 0) {
        var info = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedFeatures.length; i++) {
            info.push(selectedFeatures[i].get('GEBIETSNAME'));
        }
        //string aus der Liste erzeugen 'info.join'
        document.getElementById('infoDiv').innerHTML = info.join('<br />')
    } else {
        // wenn kein Feature ausgewählt wird, wird nichts angezeigt
        document.getElementById('infoDiv').innerHTML = '';
    }
});
```

Now, I only get the properties from some objects not all. The WFS - GeoJSON is completely homogeneous. How can this happen? There must be a mistake in this section:

polygon_source.getFeaturesAtCoordinate(p).forEach(function(feature) {
selectedFeatures.push(feature)
});

For some features I get an empty array with getFeaturesAtCoordinate(p). Why?

```
search.on('select', function(e)
    {   select.getFeatures().clear();
        select.getFeatures().push (e.search);
        var p = e.search.getGeometry().getFirstCoordinate();
        map.getView().animate({
            center: p,
            zoom: 25
        });

        var selectedFeatures = [];
        selectFeaturesGlobal = selectedFeatures;
        console.log(p);
        polygon_source.getFeaturesAtCoordinate(p).forEach(function(feature) {
        selectedFeatures.push(feature)
        console.log(feature.get('GEBIETSNAME'))
        console.log(p);
        });
        if (selectedFeatures.length > 0) {
            var info = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < selectedFeatures.length; i++) {
            info.push(selectedFeatures[i].get('GEBIETSNAME'));
            info.push(selectedFeatures[i].get('GEBIETSDATEN'));
            }
        document.getElementById('infoDiv').innerHTML = info.join('<br />')
        } else {
        document.getElementById('infoDiv').innerHTML = '';
        }
    });
```

Comment: In the line `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function(feature, layer) {` event does not have a pixel property so you are passing undefined to forEachFeatureAtPixel and causing an internal error in that function.  Also forEachFeatureAtPixel() is unlikely to work as expected while the map is animating event if your had a pixel value.  Using the coordinates you are using to center the view you could call `getFeaturesAtCoordinate().forEach()` on any vector layers you are interested in.

Comment: Thx a lot. getFeaturesAtCoordinate().forEach() works fine. But I only get some featureproperties, not all.

Comment: For some features I get a empty array with getFeaturesAtCoordinate()?

Comment: I've seen your new question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299261/getfeaturesatcoordinate-returns-empty-array and commented there